# Telerik: Calling Stored Procedures on Partial Page Postbacks with RadTabStrip

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, postback, radajaxmanager

My boss wants to use Telerik and I'm new to this so still trying to figure it out.  What I'm essentially trying to do:

- During page load, only load minimal data
- Have a navigation tab.
- When a tab is clicked, call a stored procedure specific to that tab.  A partial postback should occur so that only the relevant data is loaded.

I can accomplish this without Telerik using ASP:UpdatePanels and an unordered list of ASP:Buttons for the navbar.  I can't seem to figure out how to do it with Telerik (Telerik UI for ASP.NET)

I think I would need to combine the RadAjaxManager with the RadTabStrip (Note: within ViewPages I have nested another RadTabStrip to view Current/Past data for each Navbar item.  I'm not sure if this complicates matters.)

So my main question is basically how to make it so that "on nav tab click, call a specific function."

Here is some sample code I'm working with:

AJAX:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel runat="server" ID="LoadingPanel1" Skin="MetroTouch">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server" ID="RadAjaxManager1" EnablePageHeadUpdate="true"  EnableAJAX="true">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadTabStripAccount">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadTabStripAccount" ></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadMultiPageAccount" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

I can get the following to work without AJAX.  All the data will load at once and you can seamlessly click between tabs.  However, I only want to load one tab's info at a time and retrieve new data only when a different tab is selected.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server">
        <div class="demo-container no-bg size-narrow">
            <div class="demo-content" style="width: 900px;">
                <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="RadTabStripAccount" Orientation="VerticalLeft" AutoPostBack="false" 
                    SelectedIndex="0" MultiPageID="RadMultiPageAccount" Style="display: inline-block;
                    float: left; margin-right: 2em;" Skin="Default">
                    <Tabs>
                        <telerik:RadTab Text="Registration Applications"   Style="margin-top: 4em;"   >
                        </telerik:RadTab>
                        <telerik:RadTab Text="Role">
                        </telerik:RadTab>
                    </Tabs>
                </telerik:RadTabStrip>
                <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPageAccount" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="multiPage" Style="display: inline-block; width: 600px; height: 550px; overflow-y: auto;">
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageViewRegApp">
                        <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="RadTabStripRegApp" MultiPageID="RadMultiPageRegApp"
                            Orientation="HorizontalTop" Skin="Simple" SelectedIndex="0" Style="display: inline-block;">
                            <Tabs>
                                <telerik:RadTab Text="Current" Height="30px">
                                </telerik:RadTab>
                                <telerik:RadTab Text="Past" Height="30px">
                                </telerik:RadTab>
                            </Tabs>
                        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
                        <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPageRegApp" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="innerMultiPage"
                            Style="padding: 15px; ">
                            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageViewRegAppCurrent">
                                Applications - Current:<br />
                                <asp:Label ID="testerson" runat="server" Text="Testerson"></asp:Label>
                                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover" >
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder2"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </telerik:RadPageView>
                            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageViewRegAppPast">
                                Applications - Past:<br />
                                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder_RegAppPast"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </telerik:RadPageView>
                        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                    <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageViewRole">
                        <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="RadTabStripRole" MultiPageID="RadMultiPageRole"
                            Orientation="HorizontalTop" Skin="Simple" SelectedIndex="0" Style="display: inline-block;">
                            <Tabs>
                                <telerik:RadTab Text="Current" Height="30px" >
                                </telerik:RadTab>
                                <telerik:RadTab Text="Past" Height="30px">
                                </telerik:RadTab>
                            </Tabs>
                        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
                        <telerik:RadMultiPage RenderSelectedPageOnly="true"  runat="server" ID="RadMultiPageRole" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="innerMultiPage"
                            Style="padding: 15px;">
                            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageViewRoleCurrent">
                                Role - Current:</br>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder3"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </table>
                            </telerik:RadPageView>
                            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageViewRolePast">
                                Role - Past:<br />
                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder_MbrPast"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </table>
                            </telerik:RadPageView>
                        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
                    </telerik:RadPageView>
                </telerik:RadMultiPage>
            </div>
        </div>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```